# Extract Select Menu values from modal [discord.js]

Tags: discord.js, modal-dialog, bots

I'm currently making a modal based ordering system and extracting the TextInput works fine, however I can't seem to figure out how to extract the SelectMenu data, as the current code only returns an error
`TypeError: interaction.fields.getSelectMenuValue is not a function`

```js
client.on('interactionCreate', async interaction => {
    if (!interaction.isModalSubmit() || !interaction.customId === 'tankform') return;
    await interaction.reply({ content: 'Your order was received successfully!', ephemeral: true });
    const IGN = interaction.fields.getTextInputValue('minecraft_ign');
    const Weapon = interaction.fields.getSelectMenuValue('weapon_type');
    const ownedWeapon = interaction.fields.getSelectMenuValue('owned_weapon');
    const ownedTanks = interaction.fields.getSelectMenuValue('owned_tanks');
    const wantedTanks = interaction.fields.getSelectMenuValue('wanted_tanks');
    console.log({IGN, Weapon, ownedWeapon, ownedTanks, wantedTanks})
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code looks fine. The problem is that discord.js doesn't support recieving  select menus from modals yet. I suggest you use [discord-modals](https://www.npmjs.com/package/discord-modals). It works for me personally.

Comment: I followed the guide in the link above and edited it to my needs.
Now using ` const Weapon = modal.getSelectMenuValue('weapon_type');` , which yields
this:
`TypeError: modal.getSelectMenuValue is not a function`

Comment: Could you send some code so that I can take a look at what you wrote?

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```js
else if (interaction.type === InteractionType.ModalSubmit) // fixed
{ 
if(interaction.customId === 'yourId') {   
const IGN = interaction.fields.getTextInputValue('minecraft_ign');
    
const Weapon = interaction.fields.getSelectMenuValue('weapon_type');
    
const ownedWeapon = interaction.fields.getSelectMenuValue('owned_weapon');
    
const ownedTanks = interaction.fields.getSelectMenuValue('owned_tanks');
    
const wantedTanks = interaction.fields.getSelectMenuValue('wanted_tanks');
    console.log({IGN, Weapon, ownedWeapon, ownedTanks, wantedTanks})
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This bit

```
 if (!interaction.isModalSubmit() || !interaction.customId === 'tankform') return;
```

the 2nd comparison is incorrect, you want

```
 if (!interaction.isModalSubmit() || interaction.customId !== 'tankform') return;
```

instead